# Why does this job run on GitHub regardless of my conditional

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

I created a one job in my yaml file. It has a conditional that only allows the job to run if we are on a cat1 or cat2 branch. Here is my yaml file

```
name: cat actions
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  
jobs:
  cat:
    if: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }} == 'cat1' || startsWith(${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}, 'cat2')
    name: Publish-cat
    runs-on: [ cat ]
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Display GitHub Context
        run: |
          echo "Head Ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}"
          echo "Ref Name: ${{ github.ref_name }}"
          echo "Ref Name: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}"
```

When I ran this on my dog1 branch, it didn't ignore it in my conditional. How is this possible? I even saw the output of those values with echo and it clearly shows that my branch name is dog1. What I do know is I can have a conditional in that spot because I had done so before with just github.ref_name  and that worked for a while until it gave a weird behavior where after I would merge my feature branch into cat1 branch, it would skip the branch and I theorized that it has something to do with github.ref_name not having a value when you do a merge. In any case if anyone has any suggestions please feel free to let me know

Comment: Multiple syntax errors. See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJyVUk1LAzEQvedXDEWoguvnLVCwVrEXi/TiQWTJprPd2DVZ8tFa2v3vzqYftopST0PezHtveBMt3pGDFB6E9Mpox4zmDKAKrmjqzNhJXppZOlKuEl4SyKTRMliLWs6bkbE1oeJwtFjAWPkiZGcWc6hrakmhJZaJ0kllzdiicxy8DcgY6mnDvR12B71+Oug+3u8pFChGaSOzXO6Ippq2XSmzN5M5Hi18UwBU/g8F6HSgTdTLdtN3Xljvnmnq+GCF08i/ap9Ecx1jfApZqVyRUCOiNmiXUJ7wEhN+jaDzWLnVygDJmikLlBMT/BoGCA4pq/VNzjftm+n1dmJGK/HtCyBHuk4ywopguGDfDO7ofKWYw4Py/ZBBz2iPH192tCmH5Y4aysJAq08RwBB/SbauWz8YNAyD6Lj/HzaxHcj4O/vWJ5iE11A=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors as you don't need to use `${{ }}` in `if` condition. Please try this `if: (github.head_ref || github.ref_name) == 'cat1' || startsWith((github.head_ref || github.ref_name), 'cat2')`